# Why blank screenshot are getting attached in the extent reports when using Junit?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber, extentreports

I'm using Junit, cucumber framework for executing my test scripts. The setup and execution of code takes place on VDI.

Here is the below code, I'm using for attaching the screenshot in the Apphooks-

```
@AfterStep
    public void addScreenshot(Scenario scenario){

          final byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
          scenario.attach(screenshot, "image/png", "image"); 
        
    }
```

Below is my extent.properties file content-

```
#extent.properties
extent.reporter.spark.start=true
extent.reporter.spark.out=target/MyReports/Spark.html

#Screenshot
screenshot.dir=target/MyReports/Screenshots/
screenshot.rel.path=../Screenshots/

#Adding folder name and non repeating pattern
basefolder.name=target/MyReports
basefolder.datetimepattern=d-MMM-YY HH-mm-ss
```

*Screenshots are getting generated in the screenshot folder with the default names like embedded1, embedded2 etc.*
**But the screenshots in the extent report is showing as a small blank box below my test step. Why so?**
[image]
I don't think Output.BYTES needs a path to be explicitly given to attach the screenshots in the report.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you have to pass a full absolute path of the picture to extent repots, not a relative path.
I guess the target folder is located inside the Selenium automation project.
In case of dynamic target folder like  `target/Reports_080920222112534/Screenshots`
Let's say the Selenium project folder path is `C:\seleniumProject` and the above folder is in it, the full folder path will be `C:/seleniumProject/target/Reports_080920222112534/Screenshots`
I think the path should contain the screenshot image file itself too i.e. the full path passed to extent report should be something like `C:/seleniumProject/target/Reports_080920222112534/Screenshots/screenshot.png`

Comment: What path shall I gave in the properties file if I'm using dynamic folder path like target/Reports_080920222112534/Screenshots ?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Hi @Prophet- Thanks for the answer. If I'm using absolute path, it won't work on Jenkins. I will have to execute using relative path only.

Comment: You need to get the base path, where the project located, from the system, not to set it as hardcoded parameter. Doing so will allow your code run on any machine, local, Jenkins (Linux) etc

Comment: Hi @Prophet- I tried with both absolute and base path. It is not working either way.

Comment: I see.. I'm not sure I can help remotely..

Answer (score 0):

Providing an absolute path for the screenshot against screenshot.rel.path in the extent.properties file will help to resolve the issue.

```
@AfterStep
public void addScreenshot(Scenario scenario){
    final byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
    scenario.attach(screenshot, "image/png", "image");         
}
```

Ensure following dependencies exist

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
  <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber7-adapter</artifactId> 
  <version>1.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId> 
  <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```